# Add a search option within our own profile

Tags: feature-request, search

It would be nice if we have one more search bar within our profile or at least in favorite questions so that we can search within our activity. For Ex: i have marked many questions as my favorite so when i want to come back and search for a specific question among my own favorite questions this feature will be useful instead of searching all the questions in the site.

Comment: This is not a duplicate. Unmark it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can already do this. If you want to search within your favorites, you can use the `infavorites` search parameter:

```
infavorites:mine
```

From the [advanced search help page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/searching):

> `infavorites:mine` (or any user id) returns only questions that you (or the user whose id you entered) have favorited.

For example, say you wanted to search for `restart an Android Activity` within your favorite questions, you'd use the following search term:

> `https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=infavorites%3Amine+restart+an+Android+Activity`

[Link.](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=infavorites:mine%20restart%20an%20Android%20Activity)